# Angular 2+ (4.3.5) ngForm reset (template-driven) does't include html-form reset - Bug or Feature?

Tags: html, forms, angular, reset

I stumbled upon this question as the yellow input background in the chrome browser doesn't went away after a form reset in Angular 4.3.5

template:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    [...]
    <button (click)="angularReset()">reset Form (Angular 4)</button>
    <button (click)="htmlReset()">reset Form (HTML5)</button>
</form>
```

class:

```
@ViewChild('myForm')
private myForm: NgForm
@ViewChild('myForm', { read: ElementRef })
private myFormElementRef: ElementRef

[...]

private angularReset() {
    this.myForm.reset()
}

private htmlReset() {
    this.myFormElementRef.nativeElement.reset()
}
```

Angulars form reset method does not care about resetting the native html form obviously.

Is this a bug or a feature of Angular 4.3.5?

(The guide https://angular.io/guide/forms doesn't care about resetting the native html form. So I would say: Either the guide is incomplete or it is an angular bug.)

Comment: what do you mean here by resetting ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't set the model correctly.

It works this way:

**HTML**

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">

      <input name="input1" #input1="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="name">

      <button type="reset">reset </button>
      <button type="button" (click)="myForm.reset()">reset from template</button>
      <button type="button" (click)="onReset(myForm)">reset from class</button>
      <button type="button" (click)="onReset2()">reset from class</button>
</form>
```

**Typescript**

```
  name:string;
  @ViewChild("myForm") myForm;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  onReset(myForm){
    myForm.reset();
  }

  onReset2(){
    this.myForm.reset()
  }
```

**[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iJdZTxjkRlQ4OmEi1XSV?p=preview)**

Comment: Have you seen the plunker?